# How to change the java object input from (1,2,4) to (1,2) in Flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, mobile, tensorflow-lite

Well I am trying to integrate a tflite model into my flutter app, but I have this error

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy between a TensorFlowLite tensor with shape [1, 2] and a Java object with shape [1, 2, 4].

I think i should change the java object input from (1,2,4) to (1,2) but don't know did anyone have an idea how can I fix it?

predictImage(File image) async {
    if (image == null) return;

```
if (_model == detect) {

  await ssdMobileNet(image);
}

FileImage(image)
    .resolve(ImageConfiguration())
    .addListener((ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info, bool _) {
  setState(() {
    _imageWidth = info.image.width.toDouble();
    _imageHeight = info.image.height.toDouble();
  });
})));

setState(() {
  _image = image;
  _busy = false;
});
```

}

```
ssdMobileNet(File image) async {
var recognitions = await Tflite.detectObjectOnImage(
    path: image.path, numResultsPerClass: 1);

setState(() {
  _recognitions = recognitions;
});
```

}

And this is the errors message

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25515): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy between a TensorFlowLite tensor with shape [1, 30] and a Java object with shape [1, 30, 4].
E/AndroidRuntime(25515):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfShapeIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:342)
E/AndroidRuntime(25515):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfDataIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:305)
E/AndroidRuntime(25515):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.copyTo(Tensor.java:183)
E/AndroidRuntime(25515):    at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:166)
E/AndroidRuntime(25515):    at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:311)
E/AndroidRuntime(25515):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunSSDMobileNet.runTflite(TflitePlugin.java:622)
E/AndroidRuntime(25515):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.doInBackground(TflitePlugin.java:419)
E/AndroidRuntime(25515):    at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.doInBackground(TflitePlugin.java:393)
E/AndroidRuntime(25515):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
E/AndroidRuntime(25515):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: It would be great if you could share some code so that we could understand better.

Comment: Sure , in fact the problem is how to resize the input java object